# Dynamically created treeview format

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, treeview

**EDIT**

It was fixed by adding `width: 100%` to the css.

I have a dynamically created treeview that pulls locations as parent nodes and lists deals at those locations in the child nodes.The treeview is dynamically created, so it's not like I can put a div around it and format the div. I've tried that. The formatting in the div doesn't show up at all. I want the treeview to display like this:

_ Location A

____ Deal A

____ Deal B

____ Deal C

_ Location B

____ Deal A

____ Deal B

____ Deal C

But right now it displays centered and it looks ugly. I've tried using a div, I've tried using classes. The nodes refuse to left align and stay firmly in the center. I know the class is working because I can change the margins and the border and the background color, but nothing touches the actual text.

aspx:

```
<asp:MultiView ID="LoginView" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="VendorContent" runat="server">
            <h2>My Locations</h2>
            <hr style="margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%">
            <br />
            <div class="location" runat="server">
                <div id="treeview" runat="server">
                    <asp:TreeView ID="LocationTreeView" runat="server" Value="Left" CssClass="treeview">
                    </asp:TreeView>
                    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="saveChanges" OnClick="saveChanges_Click" Text="Save Changes" CssClass="save_treeview"/>
                <a id="newDealLink" href="deals.aspx">Make a new deal</a>
            </div>
        </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

aspx.cs:

```
This is called in the page load if the view is a vendor:

private void loadVendorTree(UserInfo userinfo)
{
    LocationTreeView.ShowCheckBoxes = TreeNodeTypes.All;

    foreach (Location location in locations)
    {
        List<int> deal_IDs = new List<int>();
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(location.Address, location.Location_id.ToString());
        node.ShowCheckBox = false;
        foreach (Deal deal in deals)
        {
            TreeNode dealNode = new TreeNode(deal.Info, deal.Deal_id.ToString());
            if(location.Deals.Contains(deal)){
                dealNode.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dealNode.Checked = false;
            }
            deal_IDs.Add(deal.Deal_id);
            dealNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
            node.ChildNodes.Add(dealNode);
        }
        LocationTreeView.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
}
```

css:

```
.treeview {
text-align: left;
margin: .5em 0;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 6em;
color: black;
border: 2px solid pink;
}

.save_treeview {
margin-left: .5em;
margin-bottom: .5em;
width: 10em;
}

.location {
text-align: left;
max-width: 45em;
margin: 0 auto;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
border: 2px solid #dcdaf1;
}
```

If anyone can help me or direct me to something that can I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try nested unordered lists like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Location A</li>
    <li>
         <ul>
              <li>Deal A</li>
              <li>Deal B</li>
              <li>Deal C</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Location B</li>
    <li>
         <ul>
              <li>Deal A</li>
              <li>Deal B</li>
              <li>Deal C</li>
         </ul>
    </li>    
 </ul>
```

Then just style the unordered lists and list items with css and you are good.